# Batch Script to rename files from folder name; issue with "-"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

Been using this script for years that I found from here for renaming movie filenames from parent foldernames:

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%x in (*) do (
 pushd "%%x"
 echo %%x
 for /F %%i in ("%%x") do (
  ren *.mkv "%%~ni.mkv" 2> NUL
  ren *.avi "%%~ni.avi" 2> NUL
  ren *.mp4 "%%~ni.mp4" 2> NUL
 )
 popd
)
```

So the only issue that I'm having is the parent folder looks like this:
MovieFolder-xyz

Running the script, the filename will be:
MovieFolder.mp4

the issue here is the "-xyz" gets omitted and I'm too simple minded to figure out how to fix this script so that I don't have to manually rename all the files.  Tia!

Comment: There is no code that specifically deals with the `-`-character, and such is nothing special to `cmd`, so your issue is not reproducible; the `for /F` command splits file names at _spaces_ and _tabs_, but not at `-`…

Comment: Eek.  So there's no workaround to somehow exporting the entire folder and then printing it into a filename?  Bummer, thanks

Comment: I agree with @aschipfl, the most likely scenrio is that your directory was named `MovieFolder.xyz`, and because you're using `%%~ni` instead of `%%~nxi` or `%%~nxx`, the last period and the characters following it are being seen as its extension, and being omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing it like that, but for the same task you could do it like this:

```batch-file
@for /r /d %%x in (*) do @(ren "%%x\*.mkv" "%%~nxx.mkv" 2> NUL
    ren "%%x\*.avi" "%%~nxx.avi" 2> NUL
    ren "%%x\*.mp4" "%%~nxx.mp4" 2> NUL)
```

Or even simpler:

```batch-file
@for /r /d %%x in (*) do @for %%y in (mkv avi mp4) do @ren "%%x\*.%%y" "%%~nxx.%%y" 2> NUL
```

*A proper script would ascertain whether there are more than one of each of those file types in the directory first, to prevent randomly renaming just one of them, or perform some additional scripting to ensure that only a specific one is renamed.*

Comment: Outstanding, this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!!

Comment: Oh cool!  Was wondering where to do that, I looked up your profile to message to thank you and ask how to make it solved, perfect, thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to bump this other thread but was wondering if you wouldn't mind having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872074/need-batch-script-to-skip-over-existing-sfv-files-when-ran-a-second-time

Comment: Not only did I provide the advice for you in the comments of that question, you even used it in your now deleted answer, _(changing to a different method of generating the `.sfv`, than in your initial post, which I had replicated)_. What exactly is the on topic issue you are facing, with it. Taking account that myself, or this site's members are not here to advise you on which utility or application you use to create the `.sfv` files.

Comment: Hey Compo I meant no disrespect to you, sorry if I screwed up was just trying to help anyone else by posting what worked in the form of an answer.  I'm a crafts tradesman not a programmer, and just needed help piecing together a batch script to simplify .sfv creation rather than having to manually create the files one at a time.  The issue I had with the answer you posted on the other script was that it had to rehash each file rather than skip over files which already had a corresponding .sfv with it.  Again sorry and let me know how I may remedy my error.

Comment: @CuJo, the code I provided, and which you replicated, creates a listing of files in the current directory, which do not have the `.sfv` extension. It then passes each item of that list to the `Do` portion, where each files' basename is checked to see if there is an existing file along side it with the same basename but with the `.sfv` extension. If there is not, the 'utility' you've chosen will then create one. No files are parsed more than once, because the `Dir` command within the loop completes before passing the output to `Do`, _(unlike the code above, which passes the items as it runs)_.

Comment: Just tried it out, somehow I screwed it up the first time around but after copying/pasting exactly what you wrote it works flawlessly.  Thanks once again truly appreciate this!  If you wouldn't mind posting it in an answer to the other question thread I'd love to mark it as answered, thanks!